# Undo buffer getting cleared after handling OnKeyDown in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am subclassing TextBox:

```
class Editor : TextBox
```

I have overridden OnKeyDown, because I want tabs to be replaced by four spaces:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) {
        SelectedText = "    ";
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

This works, but unfortunately it also clears the undo buffer.  The end result is that when the user presses tab, Ctrl+Z doesn't work and 'Undo' on the right-click menu becomes disabled.  The problem appears to be the "e.SuppressKeyPress = true;" part.

Does anyone have any idea of how to get around this?

For more info, I am creating a fairly simple text editor, and I'm handling not only the Tab key (as above), but also the Enter key.  So I have this problem with Tab and Enter.  I am aware that this problem doesn't exist with RichTextBox, but for various reasons I want to use TextBox instead.

Any help would be much appreciated, as this is a show-stopping problem in my project.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution, which is to use the Windows API as follows:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) {
        WinApi.SendMessage(Handle, WinApi.WmChar, WinApi.VkSpace, (IntPtr)4);
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Here is my WinApi class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class WinApi
{ 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public const           UInt32 WmChar  =         0x102;
    public static readonly IntPtr VkSpace = (IntPtr)0x20;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a result of overriding `OnKeyDown`, it's that you're setting `SelectedText` (any text modification will have the same effect). You can see this by commenting out your code that sets the `SelectedText` while leaving everything else. Obviously you won't get a tab or four characters, but the undo buffer will be preserved.

According to [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2006/09/10/Changing-TextBox-Text-as-an-Undo_2D00_able-Action.aspx), you should be able to use the `Paste(string)` function rather than setting the `SelectedText` property and preserve the undo buffer:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) 
    {
        Paste("    ");
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to solve the problem, although it has a side-effect:  Pressing Ctrl+Z after using Tab undoes only what has happened since the Tab insertion.  For example, typing "abc[space]def" and pressing Ctrl+Z results in "", while typing "abc[tab]def" and pressing Ctrl+Z leaves "abc".  This might not matter though; I'll see.  In any case, I guess there is no way to avoid this.  Thanks for your answer.