# How to implement custom undo in TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'd like to manually implement a basic undo system for a TextBox (because of the problems mentioned in [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653890/undo-buffer-getting-cleared-after-handling-onkeydown-in-textbox)).  I've been trying to do this for hours, but I can't find a way.  Does anybody know whether this is possible?

It seems that doing this would require, for example, detecting that the user has changed the caret position, but I can't figure out how to do this.  Sure, I can listen for the arrow keys, and detect mouse clicks, but it doesn't seem to be possible — at least in the case of the arrow keys — to actually tell whether SelectionStart has *changed*.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd grateful.

Tom

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/800940/157666 , please. There are a lot of discussion about this topic.

Comment: And which one of those talks about implementing undo for a TextBox?  I can't see it.  I'm asking a very specific question about TextBox, not a general question about implementing an undo system.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution I developed and works fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace INQ_adm.Forms.ControlsX
{
    public class TextBoxX : TextBox
    {
        private static int UNDO_LIMIT = 0;
        private List<Item> LastData = new List<Item>();
        private int undoCount = 0;
        private Boolean undo = false;

        public TextBoxX()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Z))
            {
                undo = true;
                try
                {
                    ++undoCount;
                    this.Text = LastData[LastData.Count - undoCount - 1].text;
                    this.SelectionStart = LastData[LastData.Count - undoCount - 1].position;
                    this.PerformLayout();
                }
                catch
                {
                    --undoCount;
                }

                undo = false;
                return true;
            }

            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Y))
            {
                undo = true;
                try
                {
                    --undoCount;
                    this.Text = LastData[LastData.Count - undoCount + 1].text;
                    this.SelectionStart = LastData[LastData.Count - undoCount + 1].position;
                    this.PerformLayout();
                }
                catch
                {
                    ++undoCount;
                }

                undo = false;
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }

        private void textBoxX_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!undo)
            {
                LastData.RemoveRange(LastData.Count - undoCount, undoCount);
                LastData.Add(new Item(this.Text, this.SelectionStart));
                undoCount = 0;
                    if (UNDO_LIMIT != 0 && UNDO_LIMIT + 1 < LastData.Count)
                {
                    LastData.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxX_TextChanged);
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public String text;
        public int position;

        public Item(String text, int position)
        {
            this.text = text;
            this.position = position;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you handle the `TextChanged` event and just push the textbox contents onto a stack each time it changes, then pop and refresh the `TextBox` every time the user hits Ctrl-Z?

Comment: That wouldn't highlight the new text (e.g., type something into Notepad and press Ctrl+Z a few times; the new text is highlighted when it appears), and I presume that would be very slow for large files.

Comment: In the absence of a silver bullet solution, whatever route you take will probably require optimization and a little creativeness.  I can't imagine it would be too difficult to write your own algorithm for highlighting the text changed when you do a ctrl-z..or finding and efficient one online to return the diff of two strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but sounds exactly like what you need:
[http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2006/09/10/Changing-TextBox-Text-as-an-Undo_2D00_able-Action.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20140503003821/http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2006/09/10/Changing-TextBox-Text-as-an-Undo_2D00_able-Action.aspx)

To sum up, when you do your tab replacement, simply select all of the text in the box append your 4 spaces, then paste the entire text back in the box.

This should allow the user to hit ctrl+z to undo the whole thing.  Now, I have no idea what would happen if they kept typing after doing the spaces...  I assume it would all get removed from a ctrl+z press.

Comment: Using TextBox.Paste(string) doesn't work well; it creates a new event in the undo history before adding the text.  Replace the whole text of the text box wouldn't highlight the new text, and I presume it would be slow on large files.